# EntityManager is null in Spring's Task Scheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-scheduled

I have been trying to create a job to delete all records from database. This job is deployed with my webservice. In webservice I can easily access my EntityManager and it's having no issues so far. But, whenever I try to access EntityManager in my scheduler then it gives me NullPointerException.

```
@Service
public class DeletionJob {

   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "my_pu")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=10000)
    public void run() {
        boolean flag = false;
        TypedQuery<Abc> query
                = em.createNamedQuery("deleteAll",ABC.class);
    }
}
```

This is my class but, it gives me exception on second line of run method.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan({ "com.jobs.*" })
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class AppConfig extends Application {
     @Bean
     public DeletionJob myDeletionJob() {
         return new DeletionJob();
     } 
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver 
                          = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        return viewResolver;
    }
        @Bean
        public REST getService(){
            return new REST(); 
        }
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }


    /**
     * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
     * It is automatically populated with
     * all resources defined in the project.
     * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
     */
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(com.service.REST.class);
        // Tried to include deletionjob class here but, no luck still the same.
    // resources.add(com.jobs.DeletionJob.class);
    }
}
```

I don't have any configuration file. As I am using annotations. But, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. As my all services are working fine and no issues with the database related transactions.

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="my_pu" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>ds</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: I wouldn't say you don't have any configuration file. Your AppConfig class is a configuration file. I believe you mean to say you don't have any xml-based configuration files.

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I meant to say

Comment: I don't see your EntityManager defined in the AppConfig you provided. Do you have another config class that defines the EntityManager?

Comment: It's inside DeletionJob .  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "my_pu")
    private EntityManager em;

Comment: You need to configure the entity manager somewhere to be able to inject it with `@PersistenceContext`

Comment: What is your application server?

Comment: @AndrewMairose my webservices are working fine with teh persistance Unit.

Comment: @Franck GlassFish 4.1

Comment: Then you must have another config file somewhere that defines the persistance unit.

Comment: please show your persistence.xml

Comment: @Franck Question updated

Comment: The @PersistentContext can be honored by GlassFish with an EJB component in your case it could be an EJB Timer, otherwise Spring can do that as well through the PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor component. But I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: @Franck can you kindly give an answer with an update that what I need to change in current code?

Comment: In your AppConfig try to add @Bean
    public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }

Comment: I did that. But, do I need to use this get method instead of entityManager?

Comment: no don't change anything else. Hopefully with this bean in the spring context your EntityManager wont be null.

Comment: After including this it has started giving me exception that my_pu "BeanInitializationException"